# Cancel all previous subscriptions of braintree if new subscrtiption is taken

Tags: node.js, payment-gateway, payment, braintree

My team is using braintree for making transactions. When a new subscription is taken, we want to cancel all previous subscription.But braintree cancel method takes only one subscriptionId. i.e.
**gateway.subscription.cancel("theSubscriptionId", (err, result) => {
});**
Is there any way to pass multiple subscriptionId at a time except using this method in a map method?

Comment: do you also need to find all the subscription? or do you have them already in a structure? it seems that there is no other method in the documentation, just cycle or use a map...

Comment: thanks for your concern. I do have all subscriptions in structure. But as you mentioned about a cycle or map. I also think the same and there is no othe method other than that. Thanks a lot again.